# How do I get placeid from the coordinate

Tags: php, google-maps

How do I get placeid from coordinate with php

placeid to coordinat :

```
$placeid = "eg...";
$url  = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=$placeid&language=hi&key=xxxx";
$ch = curl_init($url);
```

coordinat to placeid ?

```
$latitude = ""
$longitude = ""
$latitudeDelta = "";
$longitudeDelta = "";
```

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse geocode the coordinates of a location to be able to get its corresponding Place ID. Here's a sample request with coordinates as an input: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=37.422,-122.084057&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Sample response:

```
{ 
   plus_code:{...},
   results:[ 
      { 
         address_components:[...],
         formatted_address:"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         geometry:{...},
         place_id:"ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw",
      plus_code:{...},
     types:[...]
      }...
```

In the same way, you can also use the Geocoding API to get the coordinates of a specific Place ID.

Sample request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Sample Response:

```
{ 
   results:[ 
      { 
         address_components:[...],
         formatted_address:"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         geometry:{ 
            location:{ 
               lat:37.4219999,
               lng:-122.0840575
            },
            location_type:"ROOFTOP",
            viewport:{...}
         },
         place_id:"ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw",
         types:[...]
      }
   ],
   status:"OK"
}
```